# Let $A$ be normal operator, such that $\tan{A} + \frac{1}{\tan{A}} = 2Id.$ Prove that $A$ is hermitian operator.

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $A$ be normal operator on a finite-dimensional complex unitary space, such that $\tan{A} + \frac{1}{\tan{A}} = 2Id.$ Prove that $A$ is hermitian operator.

I was planning using theorem which says that $A$ is hermitian iff $\sigma (A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Let $$f(\lambda) = \tan{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\tan{\lambda}} - 2.$$ My idea was to observe $\sigma(f(A))$ ( which equals to $f(\sigma(A))$ ); because if $\lambda \in \sigma (A) \Rightarrow f(\lambda) \in \sigma (f(A))$.

Solving the equation $$ \tan{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\tan{\lambda}} - 2 = 0,$$ I got $\lambda_{1,2} = 1 +/- \sqrt{2}$, which means that $A$ is hermitian. Is that good thinking?